# How to "sync" two arrays using knockout computed?

Tags: knockout.js

I have two arrays for my webpage - the first is a list of all items available, and the second is a filtered list populated by specific items from the first list.  The second list is populated by clicking an element and calling the function to loop through looking for specific data:

```
self.populate = function() {
    self.visibleEmails([]);
    for (var i = 0; i < self.emails().length; i++) {
        if (self.emails()[i].folder() == this.name) {
            self.visibleEmails.push(self.emails()[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, however if I modify the master array of all items, I have to click again to repopulate the second array since it doesn't know any changes were made yet.  I read about computed observables being able to update the observable if changes were made to a dependent, so I was wondering if that was something possible in this case?

For a full look at my application you can check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/s0dhzd2t/55/

If you look at the example, you can see what I mean if you try deleting or moving an item(s). It technically works, but you need to click the folder on the left again in order to see the changes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`computed` is what ko is all about and here's how you'd use one for this:

```
self.visibleEmails = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.emails().filter(function(e) { 
        return e.folder() == self.selectedFolder().name; 
    });
});
```

Because it invokes `emails()` it will be re-evaluated whenever `emails` changes.

Adopt this style for *everything* and you will reap many benefits.

http://jsfiddle.net/s0dhzd2t/57/

Comment: So, do I put this inside my .populate observable? Sorry for my arrogance, but I'm pretty new to knockout, and I want to make sure I'm doing this correctly. Any chance you could show me in my jsFiddle, so that I can see exactly what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: Basically you would do it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/s0dhzd2t/56/), by (1) adding a `selectedFolder` observable  (holding the name property), (2) transferring your filter logic inside `visibleEmails`, a computed observable, and (3) changing the `populate` function to simply update the `selectedFolder`

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes so much more sense to do it this way!

Comment: No problem, welcome to the magical world of `ko.computed`, you can make another computed that depends on this one, etc. everything will stay in sync... this is ko's secret sauce.